# ASP.NET Upload file return its content

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to upload a file then retrieve its content as JSon

My controller :

```
controller.cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
List<string> list = doStuff(file);
return Json(list);
}
```

My view :

```
view.cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{  
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
}
```

When I upload a file it propose me to download a JSON file, but what I want is to set a javascript variable with this JSON so I can use it directly on my webpage.

Comment: Then you probably need to do an AJAX request, not a plain old POST.

Comment: If prompted to download a file then it is likely that the [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) is being set [incorrectly] to "attachment", much as if the file was being downloaded for-real. Make sure that such is a not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best solution is to use an ajax form.

See the example below:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    return Json(new { ReturnMessage = "Success!!!!!" + file.FileName});
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id="formUploadFile", @onsubmit = "return SubmitFormWithFile();" }))
{

    @Html.TextBox("file", null, new { @type = "file", @id = "file" })

    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

Javascript:

```
    function SubmitFormWithFile() {
        var form = $("#formUploadFile");

        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            data: new FormData(form[0]),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                alert("Before Send");
            },
            success: function (dataResult) {
                //set its variable here...
                //the dataResult is returned json...

                alert(dataResult.ReturnMessage);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```